# Rstudio Server: Cannot start H2O.init on Centos

Tags: rstudio, h2o

H2o cannot start successfully, but I still can access link
localhost:12345/flow/index.html

**Log in R Studio**

Error in h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = "4g", ip = "localhost",  : 
  H2O failed to start, stopping execution.

**Log in OS**

```
[root@xxxx]# tail -200f /tmp/RtmpYou3gq/h2o_tuongnv4_started_from_r.out


: ----- H2O started  -----
: Build git branch: rel-ueno
: Build git hash: f521cfeb6cf6c41ca6a728cdbaafe96509170907
: Build git describe: jenkins-3.10.4.5-4-gf521cfe
: Build project version: 3.10.4.6 (latest version: unknown)
: Build age: 15 days
: Built by: 'jenkins'
: Built on: '2017-04-26 22:11:30'
: Watchdog Build git branch: (unknown)
: Watchdog Build git hash: (unknown)
: Watchdog Build git describe: (unknown)
: Watchdog Build project version: (unknown)
: Watchdog Built by: (unknown)
: Watchdog Built on: (unknown)
: Processed H2O arguments: [-name, H2O_started_from_R_tuongnv4_tju329, -ip, localhost, -port, 12345, -ice_root, /tmp/RtmpYou3gq]
: Java availableProcessors: 8
: Java heap totalMemory: 238.0 MB
: Java heap maxMemory: 3.56 GB
: Java version: Java 1.8.0_131 (from Oracle Corporation)
: JVM launch parameters: [-Xmx4g, -ea]
: OS version: Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 (amd64)
: Machine physical memory: 15.44 GB
: X-h2o-cluster-id: 1494587541855
: User name: 'tuongnv4'
: Opted out of sending usage metrics.
: IPv6 stack selected: false
: Possible IP Address: enp0s31f6 (enp0s31f6), 192.168.170.166
: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 127.0.0.1
: Selected H2O.CLOUD_MULTICAST_IF: name:lo (lo) doesn't support multicast
: H2O node running in unencrypted mode.
: Internal communication uses port: 12346
: Listening for HTTP and REST traffic on http://127.0.0.1:12345/
: H2O cloud name: 'H2O_started_from_R_tuongnv4_tju329' on localhost/127.0.0.1:12345, discovery address /228.246.241.107:58614
: If you have trouble connecting, try SSH tunneling from your local machine (e.g., via port 55555):
:   1. Open a terminal and run 'ssh -L 55555:localhost:12345 tuongnv4@127.0.0.1'
:   2. Point your browser to http://localhost:55555
: Log dir: '/tmp/RtmpYou3gq/h2ologs'
: Cur dir: '/home/tuongnv4'
: HDFS subsystem successfully initialized
: S3 subsystem successfully initialized
: Flow dir: '/home/tuongnv4/h2oflows'
: Cloud of size 1 formed [localhost/127.0.0.1:12345]
: Registered parsers: [GUESS, ARFF, XLS, SVMLight, AVRO, PARQUET, CSV]
: Watchdog extension initialized
: Registered 1 extensions in: 2mS
: Registered: 148 REST APIs in: 283mS
: Registered: 209 schemas in 333ms
: H2O started in 2128ms
: 
: Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://127.0.0.1:12345
: 
: GET /flow/index.html, parms: {}
: GET /flow/index.html, parms: {}
: GET /3/Metadata/endpoints, parms: {}
: Locking cloud to new members, because hex.schemas.DeepLearningV3
: GET /flow/help/catalog.json, parms: {}
: GET /3/ModelBuilders, parms: {}
: GET /3/NodePersistentStorage/categories/environment/names/clips/exists, parms: {}
: GET /3/About, parms: {}
: GET /3/NodePersistentStorage/notebook, parms: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly what's happening here is server configuration issues.

For starters I recommend:

- disable any linux firewall (iptables/iptables6)
- disable SElinux

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting on a non-standard port (12345 instead of the default 54321).

Try removing the `port` argument to `h2o.init()`, and it will probably work fine.

(There is, or used to be, a bug in the handling of the port argument, which might be what you are hitting. I believe the workaround was to manually start h2o.jar from the commandline (i.e. outside of R), and then `h2o.init(port=12345)` should be able to connect to it.)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one other thing that might be happening...

If you are able to connect to H2O using the web browser but not from within R, then you might have proxy environment variables that need to be unset from within R.

Make sure the environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy are unset within the R session.

Comment: rite! We should remove proxy before Run h2o:
 Sys.unsetenv("http_proxy")

Comment: Hi Tuong, does it make sense to accept this answer then?